# Trouble with comp function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have 3 previous files with a function each and am trying to use comp in ex4.clj to combine all 3 but am currently getting an error about the wrong number of args being passed. I've tried using map, reduce, and filter with it but they all fail and I'm not sure how to tell which one would be desired since all functions use a different one.

*ex1.clj*

```
(defn round [input] (Math/round (double input)))

(def testList [4.7 3.3 -17 17 -5.6 -3.3 0])

(def roundedList (map round testList))
```

*ex2.clj*

```
(defn isDivisibleBy [factor]
    (fn [number]
        (def result (/ number factor))
        (def roundedResult (Math/round (double result)))

        (and (= result roundedResult))
    )
)

(def divisibleBy2 (isDivisibleBy 2))

(def testList [2 3 4 17 3000 -3 -6 0])

(def divisibleSuccess (filter divisibleBy2 testList))
```

*ex3.clj*

```
(defn findMax [accum value]
    (if (> accum value) accum value)
)

(def testList [2 3 4 17 3000 -3 0 -3001])
(def maxValue (reduce findMax testList))
```

*ex4.clj* (Problem file)

```
(load-file "ex1.clj")
(load-file "ex2.clj")
(load-file "ex3.clj")

(def testList [4.7 3.3 -17 17 -5.6 -3.3 0])
(def allThree (comp findMax divisibleBy2 round))
(def output ((map/reduce/filter) allThree testList))

(println "Original list: " testList)
(println "Highest rounded number divisible by 2: " output)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I just put that there to symbolize that I tried all three. Apologies for the confusion. I only put one at a time when testing. I get the same error even when combining into one file.

Comment: What do you hope this composed function will do? Can you write an equivalent function without using comp?

Comment: @amalloy The function should take a list, round them, filter based on divisibility by 2, and then return the highest value. The part the code seems to get stuck on is that findMax expects 2 arguments but the comp function is only passing it one. I was attempting to rewrite it in a curried form but was running into issues with that as well. We have to use the comp function for the assignment.

The error now is:
Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user/findMax

Comment: @amalloy I can manually accomplish this w/ 3 different commands that just take the output from the last and put it into the next one which is what I thought comp essentially did but it doesn't seem to work the same.
(def roundedList (map round testList))
(def divisibleSuccess (filter divisibleBy2 roundedList))
(def output (reduce findMax divisibleSuccess))

We're just touching on Clojure and the professor provided examples and a guide for using all of the other functions but nothing much on the comp function and all of the online info seems to either be to complicated or non existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions there are used for different jobs: one is a predicate,
you want to `filter` with.  One is a transformation, you want to `map`
over.  And the last one is an aggregate, you want to use as final step
(via `reduce`).

So you have to compose over the transformations you want to do:

```clj
((comp
    (partial reduce findMax)
    (partial filter divisibleBy2)
    (partial map round))
  testList)
```

If you want to do that alot, you should also have a look at
[transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers), which allow
doing this without the cost of intermediate sequences.

Random style critique:

- Clojure uses `kebab-case` and not `camelCase`
- Never `def` outside of the namespace; use `let` instead
- It's common to have a trailing `?` on predicates (e.g. `divisible-by-2?`)

Comment: Thanks for all the great tips and the helpful response!